# Fantasy Character Creation Tool (early prototype)

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, c++14

I recently started studying C++ programming; while attending the course I'm writing a program on the side as a personal project to familiarize with what I'm learning. It is still very basic and I'm sure that as I begin learning OOP there will be a lot of room for improving it. But for now I would like your feedback / suggestion to understand if the logic / coding I wrote is correct and where I could have done it better. Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const char* choose_race();
const char* choose_character_class();
bool define_strength(int& strength, int& unassigned_points);
bool define_dexterity(int& dexterity, int& unassigned_points);
bool define_constitution(int& constitution, int& unassigned_points);
bool define_intellect(int& intellect, int& unassigned_points);
bool define_wisdom(int& wisdom, int& unassigned_points);
bool define_charisma(int& charisma, int& unassigned_points);
bool race_stats_mod(int race, int& strength, int& dexterity, int& constitution, int& intellect, int& wisdom, int& charisma);

int main()
{
    cout << "***** Fantasy Character Creation Tool *****" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // ABILITY SCORE MODIFIERS TABLE INITIALIZATION

    vector<vector<int>> ability_score_modifier(45, vector<int>(2));
    
    ability_score_modifier.at(0).at(0) = 1;
    ability_score_modifier.at(0).at(1) = -5;

    int counter{ 2 };
    int modifier{ -4 };
    
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            ability_score_modifier.at(counter - 1).at(0) = counter;
            ability_score_modifier.at(counter - 1).at(1) = modifier;
            counter++;
        }
        modifier++;
    } while (counter<=45);

    // GENERAL VARIABLE INIZIALIZATION

    int level{ 1 };
    int experience{ 0 };
    int strength{ 10 }, dexterity{ 10 }, constitution{ 10 }, intellect{ 10 }, wisdom{ 10 }, charisma{ 10 };

    // CHOOSE RACE

    string race;
    race = choose_race();
    system("cls");

    // CHOOSE CLASS

    string character_class;
    character_class = choose_character_class();
    system("cls");

    // CHOOSE NAME

    string name;
    cout << "Enter your character name: ";
    cin >> name;
    system("cls");

    // MODIFY ATTRIBUTES VALUES BASED ON CHOOSEN RACE

    int race_to_integer{};
    if (race == "Human")
    {
        race_to_integer = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (race == "Dwarf")
        {
            race_to_integer = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (race == "Elf")
            {
                race_to_integer = 3;
            }
        }
    }

    bool check_if_selection_success{ false };
    
    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = race_stats_mod(race_to_integer, strength, dexterity, constitution, intellect, wisdom, charisma);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false);

    system("cls");

    // ASSIGN ATTRIBUTE STATS

    cout << "SELECT YOUR CHARACTER ATTRIBUTES" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Current stats:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "STRENGTH: " << strength << endl;
    cout << "DEXTERITY: " << dexterity << endl;
    cout << "CONSTITUTION: " << constitution << endl;
    cout << "INTELLECT: " << intellect << endl;
    cout << "WISDOM: " << wisdom << endl;
    cout << "CHARISMA: " << charisma << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    int unassigned_points{ 15 };

    cout << "Available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Points gained or spent based on attribute values:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "7 / gain 4 point" << endl;
    cout << "8 / gain 2 point" << endl;
    cout << "9 / gain 1 point" << endl;
    cout << "11 --> 13 / 1 point each" << endl;
    cout << "14 --> 15 / 2 points each" << endl;
    cout << "16 --> 17 / 3 points each" << endl;
    cout << "18 / 4 points" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = define_strength(strength, unassigned_points);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false); 
    
    cout << "Remaining available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    check_if_selection_success = false;
    
    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = define_dexterity(dexterity, unassigned_points);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false);

    cout << "Remaining available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    check_if_selection_success = false;

    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = define_constitution(constitution, unassigned_points);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false);

    cout << "Remaining available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    check_if_selection_success = false;

    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = define_intellect(intellect, unassigned_points);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false);

    cout << "Remaining available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    check_if_selection_success = false;

    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = define_wisdom(wisdom, unassigned_points);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false);

    cout << "Remaining available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    check_if_selection_success = false;

    do
    {
        check_if_selection_success = define_charisma(charisma, unassigned_points);
    } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
    
    // CHECK IF ALL ATTRIBUTE POINTS HAVE BEEN ASSIGNED OR NOT
    // IN CASE THERE ARE REMAINING POINTS IT WILL PROMPT THE USER TO RECONSIDER THE PREVIOUS SELECTION

    if (unassigned_points>0)
    {
        cout << "You did not assign all available points." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        while (unassigned_points>0)
        {
        cout << "Remaining available points: " << unassigned_points << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Witch attribute would you like to change:" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "[1] Strength = " << strength << endl;
        cout << "[2] Dexterity = " << dexterity << endl;
        cout << "[3] Constitution = " << constitution << endl;
        cout << "[4] Intellect = " << intellect << endl;
        cout << "[5] Wisdom = " << wisdom << endl;
        cout << "[6] Charisma = " << charisma << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Selection: ";
        int change_attribute{};
        cin >> change_attribute;
        switch (change_attribute)
        {
        case 1:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_strength(strength, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_dexterity(dexterity, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_constitution(constitution, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_intellect(intellect, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_wisdom(wisdom, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_charisma(charisma, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong selection. Try again." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    
    // DEFINE THE ATTRIBUTES MOD VALUES BASED ON FINAL ATTRIBUTES AND ABILITY SCORES VECTOR

    int strength_mod{}, dexterity_mod{}, constitution_mod{}, intellect_mod{}, wisdom_mod{}, charisma_mod{};

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (strength == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            strength_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (dexterity == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            dexterity_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (constitution == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            constitution_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (intellect == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            intellect_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (wisdom == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            wisdom_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (charisma == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            charisma_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }

    system("cls");

    // PRINT OUT THE CHARACTER SHEET

    cout << "***** YOUR CHARACTER *****" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << name << " - LVL " << level << endl;
    cout << race << " " << character_class << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "PRIMARY STATS: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "STRENGTH: " << strength << " - mod: " << strength_mod << endl;
    cout << "DEXTERITY: " << dexterity << " - mod: " << dexterity_mod << endl;
    cout << "CONSTITUTION: " << constitution << " - mod: " << constitution_mod << endl;
    cout << "INTELLECT: " << intellect << " - mod: " << intellect_mod << endl;
    cout << "WISDOM: " << wisdom << " - mod: " << wisdom_mod << endl;
    cout << "CHARISMA: " << charisma << " - mod: " << charisma_mod << endl;

    return 0;
}

const char* choose_race()
{
    int race{};
    char confirm_choice{ 'n' };

    cout << "Select your character race: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "[1] Human" << endl;
    cout << "[2] Dwarf" << endl;
    cout << "[3] Elf" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Selection: ";
    cin >> race;
    switch (race)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "In the reckonings of most worlds, humans are the youngest of the common races," << endl; 
        cout << "late to arrive on the world sceneand short - lived in comparison to dwarves," << endl;
        cout << "elves, and dragons. Perhaps it is because of their shorter lives that they strive" << endl;
        cout << "to achieve as much as they can in the years they are given. Or maybe they feel" << endl; 
        cout << "they have something to prove to the elder races, and that’s why they build their" << endl; 
        cout << "mighty empires on the foundation of conquestand trade. Whatever drives them," << endl; 
        cout << "humans are the innovators, the achievers, and the pioneers of the worlds." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
        cin >> confirm_choice;
        if (confirm_choice == 'n')
        {
            system("cls");
            choose_race();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Human";
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Kingdoms rich in ancient grandeur, halls carved into the roots of mountains," << endl;
        cout << "the echoing of picks and hammers in deep mines and blazing forges, a commitment" << endl;
        cout << "to clan and tradition, and a burning hatred of goblins and orcs — these common" << endl;
        cout << "threads unite all dwarves." << endl;
        cout << "Bold and hardy, dwarves are known as skilled warriors, miners, and workers" << endl;
        cout << "of stone and metal. Though they stand well under 5 feet tall, dwarves are so broad" << endl;
        cout << "and compact that they can weigh as much as a human standing nearly two feet taller." << endl;
        cout << "Their courage and endurance are also easily a match for any of the larger folk." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
        cin >> confirm_choice;
        if (confirm_choice == 'n')
        {
            system("cls");
            choose_race();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Dwarf";
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Elves are a magical people of otherworldly grace, living in the world but not entirely" << endl;
        cout << "part of it. They live in places of ethereal beauty, in the midst of ancient forests" << endl;
        cout << "or in silvery spires glittering with faerie light, where soft music drifts through" << endl;
        cout << "the air and gentle fragrances waft on the breeze. Elves love nature and magic, art" << endl;
        cout << "and artistry, music and poetry, and the good things of the world." << endl;
        cout << "With their unearthly grace and fine features, elves appear hauntingly beautiful to" << endl;
        cout << "humans and members of many other races. They are slightly shorter than humans on average," << endl;
        cout << "ranging from well under 5 feet tall to just over 6 feet. They are more slender than humans," << endl;
        cout << "weighing only 100 to 145 pounds. Males and females are about the same height, and males" << endl;
        cout << "are only marginally heavier than females." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
        cin >> confirm_choice;
        if (confirm_choice == 'n')
        {
            system("cls");
            choose_race();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Elf";
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong input. Try again!" << endl; 
        system("cls"); 
        choose_race();
    }
}

const char* choose_character_class()
{
    int character_class{};
    char confirm_choice{ 'n' };

    cout << "Select your character class: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "[1] Fighter" << endl;
    cout << "[2] Mage" << endl;
    cout << "[3] Rogue" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Selection: ";
    cin >> character_class;
    switch (character_class)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Some take up arms for glory, wealth, or revenge. Others do battle to prove themselves, to" << endl;
        cout << "protect others, or because they know nothing else. Still others learn the ways of weaponcraft to" << endl;
        cout << "hone their bodies in battle and prove their mettle in the forge of war. Lords of the battlefield," << endl;
        cout << "fighters are a disparate lot, training with many weapons or just one, perfecting the uses of" << endl;
        cout << "armor, learning the fighting techniques of exotic masters, and studying the art of combat, all to" << endl;
        cout << "shape themselves into living weapons. Far more than mere thugs, these skilled warriors reveal" << endl;
        cout << "the true deadliness of their weapons, turning hunks of metal into arms capable of taming" << endl;
        cout << "kingdoms, slaughtering monsters, and rousing the hearts of armies. Soldiers, knights, hunters," << endl;
        cout << "and artists of war, fighters are unparalleled champions, and woe to those who dare stand" << endl;
        cout << "against them." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "ROLE: Fighters excel at combat—defeating their enemies, controlling the flow of battle, and" << endl;
        cout << "surviving such sorties themselves. While their specific weapons and methods grant them a wide" << endl;
        cout << "variety of tactics, few can match fighters for sheer battle prowess." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "PREFERRED ATTRIBUTES: Strength / Constitution" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
        cin >> confirm_choice;
        if (confirm_choice == 'n')
        {
            system("cls");
            choose_character_class();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Fighter";
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Beyond the veil of the mundane hide the secrets of absolute power. The works of beings beyond" << endl;
        cout << "mortals, the legends of realms where gods and spirits tread, the lore of creations both wondrous" << endl;
        cout << "and terrible—such mysteries call to those with the ambition and the intellect to rise above the" << endl;
        cout << "common folk to grasp true might. Such is the path of the wizard. These shrewd magic-users" << endl;
        cout << "seek, collect, and covet esoteric knowledge, drawing on cultic arts to work wonders beyond the" << endl;
        cout << "abilities of mere mortals. While some might choose a particular field of magical study and" << endl;
        cout << "become masters of such powers, others embrace versatility, reveling in the unbounded wonders" << endl;
        cout << "of all magic. In either case, wizards prove a cunning and potent lot, capable of smiting their foes," << endl;
        cout << "empowering their allies, and shaping the world to their every desire." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "ROLE: While universalist wizards might study to prepare themselves for any manner of danger," << endl;
        cout << "specialist wizards research schools of magic that make them exceptionally skilled within a" << endl;
        cout << "specific focus. Yet no matter their specialty, all wizards are masters of the impossible and can aid" << endl;
        cout << "their allies in overcoming any danger." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "PREFERRED ATTRIBUTES: Intellect" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
        cin >> confirm_choice;
        if (confirm_choice == 'n')
        {
            system("cls");
            choose_character_class();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Mage";
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Life is an endless adventure for those who live by their wits. Ever just one step ahead of danger," << endl;
        cout << "rogues bank on their cunning, skill, and charm to bend fate to their favor. Never knowing what to" << endl;
        cout << "expect, they prepare for everything, becoming masters of a wide variety of skills, training" << endl;
        cout << "themselves to be adept manipulators, agile acrobats, shadowy stalkers, or masters of any of" << endl;
        cout << "dozens of other professions or talents. Thieves and gamblers, fast talkers and diplomats, bandits" << endl;
        cout << "and bounty hunters, and explorers and investigators all might be considered rogues, as well as" << endl;
        cout << "countless other professions that rely upon wits, prowess, or luck. Although many rogues favor" << endl;
        cout << "cities and the innumerable opportunities of civilization, some embrace lives on the road," << endl;
        cout << "journeying far, meeting exotic people, and facing fantastic danger in pursuit of equally fantastic" << endl;
        cout << "riches. In the end, any who desire to shape their fates and live life on their own terms might" << endl;
        cout << "come to be called rogues." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "ROLE: Rogues excel at moving about unseen and catching foes unaware, and tend to avoid head-" << endl;
        cout << "to-head combat. Their varied skills and abilities allow them to be highly versatile, with great" << endl;
        cout << "variations in expertise existing between different rogues. Most, however, excel in overcoming" << endl;
        cout << "hindrances of all types, from unlocking doors and disarming traps to outwitting magical hazards" << endl;
        cout << "and conning dull-witted opponents." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "PREFERRED ATTRIBUTES: Dexterity / Wisdom" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
        cin >> confirm_choice;
        if (confirm_choice == 'n')
        {
            system("cls");
            choose_character_class();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Rogue";
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong input. Try again!" << endl;
        system("cls");
        choose_character_class();
    }
}

bool define_strength(int& strength, int& unassigned_points)
{
    int temp_strength{};
    char confirm_new_value{};
    int required_points{ 0 };

    cout << "Target strength (Min value is 7 / Max value is 18): ";
    cin >> temp_strength;
    cout << endl;

    if (temp_strength < 7 || temp_strength > 18)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (confirm_new_value == 0)
    {
        if (temp_strength > strength)
        {
            for (int i = strength; i < temp_strength; i++)
            {
                if (i < 13)
                {
                    required_points++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
                    {
                        required_points += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
                        {
                            required_points += 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            required_points += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp_strength < strength)
            {
                for (int i = strength; i > temp_strength; i--)
                {
                    if (i==18)
                    {
                        required_points -= 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i<18 && i>=16)
                        {
                            required_points -= 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i<16 && i>=14)
                            {
                                required_points -= 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i<14 && i>10)
                                {
                                    required_points--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i==10)
                                    {
                                        required_points--;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (i==9)
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 2;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 4;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (required_points > unassigned_points)
        {
            cout << "Not enough free points. Try again." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Assigning this value requires " << required_points << " points." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to proceed? Y/N --> ";
            cin >> confirm_new_value;
            cout << endl;
            switch (confirm_new_value)
            {
            case 'Y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                strength = temp_strength;
                return true;
            case 'y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                strength = temp_strength;
                return true;
            case 'N':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            case 'n':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool define_dexterity(int& dexterity, int& unassigned_points)
{
    int temp_dexterity{};
    char confirm_new_value{};
    int required_points{ 0 };

    cout << "Target dexterity (Min value is 7 / Max value is 18): ";
    cin >> temp_dexterity;
    cout << endl;

    if (temp_dexterity < 7 || temp_dexterity > 18)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (confirm_new_value == 0)
    {
        if (temp_dexterity > dexterity)
        {
            for (int i = dexterity; i < temp_dexterity; i++)
            {
                if (i < 13)
                {
                    required_points++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
                    {
                        required_points += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
                        {
                            required_points += 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            required_points += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp_dexterity < dexterity)
            {
                for (int i = dexterity; i > temp_dexterity; i--)
                {
                    if (i == 18)
                    {
                        required_points -= 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < 18 && i >= 16)
                        {
                            required_points -= 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i < 16 && i >= 14)
                            {
                                required_points -= 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i < 14 && i>10)
                                {
                                    required_points--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i == 10)
                                    {
                                        required_points--;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (i == 9)
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 2;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 4;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (required_points > unassigned_points)
        {
            cout << "Not enough free points. Try again." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Assigning this value requires " << required_points << " points." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to proceed? Y/N --> ";
            cin >> confirm_new_value;
            cout << endl;
            switch (confirm_new_value)
            {
            case 'Y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                dexterity = temp_dexterity;
                return true;
            case 'y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                dexterity = temp_dexterity;
                return true;
            case 'N':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            case 'n':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool define_constitution(int& constitution, int& unassigned_points)
{
    int temp_constitution{};
    char confirm_new_value{};
    int required_points{ 0 };

    cout << "Target constitution (Min value is 7 / Max value is 18): ";
    cin >> temp_constitution;
    cout << endl;

    if (temp_constitution < 7 || temp_constitution > 18)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (confirm_new_value == 0)
    {
        if (temp_constitution > constitution)
        {
            for (int i = constitution; i < temp_constitution; i++)
            {
                if (i < 13)
                {
                    required_points++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
                    {
                        required_points += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
                        {
                            required_points += 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            required_points += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp_constitution < constitution)
            {
                for (int i = constitution; i > temp_constitution; i--)
                {
                    if (i == 18)
                    {
                        required_points -= 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < 18 && i >= 16)
                        {
                            required_points -= 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i < 16 && i >= 14)
                            {
                                required_points -= 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i < 14 && i>10)
                                {
                                    required_points--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i == 10)
                                    {
                                        required_points--;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (i == 9)
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 2;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 4;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (required_points > unassigned_points)
        {
            cout << "Not enough free points. Try again." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Assigning this value requires " << required_points << " points." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to proceed? Y/N --> ";
            cin >> confirm_new_value;
            cout << endl;
            switch (confirm_new_value)
            {
            case 'Y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                constitution = temp_constitution;
                return true;
            case 'y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                constitution = temp_constitution;
                return true;
            case 'N':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            case 'n':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool define_intellect(int& intellect, int& unassigned_points)
{
    int temp_intellect{};
    char confirm_new_value{};
    int required_points{ 0 };

    cout << "Target intellect (Min value is 7 / Max value is 18): ";
    cin >> temp_intellect;
    cout << endl;

    if (temp_intellect < 7 || temp_intellect > 18)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (confirm_new_value == 0)
    {
        if (temp_intellect > intellect)
        {
            for (int i = intellect; i < temp_intellect; i++)
            {
                if (i < 13)
                {
                    required_points++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
                    {
                        required_points += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
                        {
                            required_points += 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            required_points += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp_intellect < intellect)
            {
                for (int i = intellect; i > temp_intellect; i--)
                {
                    if (i == 18)
                    {
                        required_points -= 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < 18 && i >= 16)
                        {
                            required_points -= 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i < 16 && i >= 14)
                            {
                                required_points -= 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i < 14 && i>10)
                                {
                                    required_points--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i == 10)
                                    {
                                        required_points--;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (i == 9)
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 2;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 4;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (required_points > unassigned_points)
        {
            cout << "Not enough free points. Try again." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Assigning this value requires " << required_points << " points." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to proceed? Y/N --> ";
            cin >> confirm_new_value;
            cout << endl;
            switch (confirm_new_value)
            {
            case 'Y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                intellect = temp_intellect;
                return true;
            case 'y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                intellect = temp_intellect;
                return true;
            case 'N':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            case 'n':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool define_wisdom(int& wisdom, int& unassigned_points)
{
    int temp_wisdom{};
    char confirm_new_value{};
    int required_points{ 0 };

    cout << "Target wisdom (Min value is 7 / Max value is 18): ";
    cin >> temp_wisdom;
    cout << endl;

    if (temp_wisdom < 7 || temp_wisdom > 18)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (confirm_new_value == 0)
    {
        if (temp_wisdom > wisdom)
        {
            for (int i = wisdom; i < temp_wisdom; i++)
            {
                if (i < 13)
                {
                    required_points++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
                    {
                        required_points += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
                        {
                            required_points += 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            required_points += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp_wisdom < wisdom)
            {
                for (int i = wisdom; i > temp_wisdom; i--)
                {
                    if (i == 18)
                    {
                        required_points -= 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < 18 && i >= 16)
                        {
                            required_points -= 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i < 16 && i >= 14)
                            {
                                required_points -= 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i < 14 && i>10)
                                {
                                    required_points--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i == 10)
                                    {
                                        required_points--;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (i == 9)
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 2;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 4;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (required_points > unassigned_points)
        {
            cout << "Not enough free points. Try again." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Assigning this value requires " << required_points << " points." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to proceed? Y/N --> ";
            cin >> confirm_new_value;
            cout << endl;
            switch (confirm_new_value)
            {
            case 'Y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                wisdom = temp_wisdom;
                return true;
            case 'y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                wisdom = temp_wisdom;
                return true;
            case 'N':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            case 'n':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool define_charisma(int& charisma, int& unassigned_points)
{
    int temp_charisma{};
    char confirm_new_value{};
    int required_points{ 0 };

    cout << "Target charisma (Min value is 7 / Max value is 18): ";
    cin >> temp_charisma;
    cout << endl;
    
    if (temp_charisma < 7 || temp_charisma > 18)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (confirm_new_value == 0)
    {
        if (temp_charisma > charisma)
        {
            for (int i = charisma; i < temp_charisma; i++)
            {
                if (i < 13)
                {
                    required_points++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
                    {
                        required_points += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
                        {
                            required_points += 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            required_points += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp_charisma < charisma)
            {
                for (int i = charisma; i > temp_charisma; i--)
                {
                    if (i == 18)
                    {
                        required_points -= 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < 18 && i >= 16)
                        {
                            required_points -= 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i < 16 && i >= 14)
                            {
                                required_points -= 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (i < 14 && i>10)
                                {
                                    required_points--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (i == 10)
                                    {
                                        required_points--;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (i == 9)
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 2;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            required_points -= 4;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (required_points > unassigned_points)
        {
            cout << "Not enough free points. Try again." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Assigning this value requires " << required_points << " points." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to proceed? Y/N --> ";
            cin >> confirm_new_value;
            cout << endl;
            switch (confirm_new_value)
            {
            case 'Y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                charisma = temp_charisma;
                return true;
            case 'y':
                unassigned_points -= required_points;
                charisma = temp_charisma;
                return true;
            case 'N':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            case 'n':
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input. Try again." << endl;
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool race_stats_mod(int race, int& strength, int& dexterity, int& constitution, int& intellect, int& wisdom, int& charisma)
{
    int selection{};
    switch (race)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "As a human you can choose witch attribute will benefit from a +2 bonus." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Select witch attribute you want to improve:" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "[1] Strength" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Dexterity" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Constitution" << endl;
        cout << "[4] Intellect" << endl;
        cout << "[5] Wisdom" << endl;
        cout << "[6] Charisma" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1: strength += 2; return true;
        case 2: dexterity += 2; return true;
        case 3: constitution += 2; return true;
        case 4: intellect += 2; return true;
        case 5: wisdom += 2; return true;
        case 6: charisma += 2; return true;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong selection. Try again." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            return false;
        }
    case 2:
        constitution = wisdom += 2;
        charisma -= 2;
        return true;
    case 3:
        dexterity = intellect += 2;
        constitution -= 2;
        return true;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong selection. Try again." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To the best of your knowledge- does the code function as expected? And it would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply :) Yes up to now the code works as intended, at least this is what I can say based on many different case testing I did

Answer (score 5):

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

[⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

---

My first impression is that you have a bunch of free functions, not a class.  And those parameters are all primitive types, and passed by non-const reference.  I'm guessing those similarly-named parameters should be data members instead of in/out parameters.

```
// GENERAL VARIABLE INIZIALIZATION

    int level{ 1 };
    int experience{ 0 };
    int strength{ 10 }, dexterity{ 10 }, constitution{ 10 }, intellect{ 10 }, wisdom{ 10 }, charisma{ 10 };
```

Those should probably be the various **data members** of your class.

Don't put more than one variable (or class data member) declaration in a statement.

So, put a `class` around this, making these the data members.  Then remove all the similarly-named parameters from the functions, as they will all be able to access the members of the class directly.  This is basic Object Oriented principles.

---

`vector<vector<int>> ability_score_modifier(45, vector<int>(2));`
You never call `push_back` but simply pre-define the vector of vectors to a fixed size, and then access those elements.  This is inefficient and is not making use of the main feature of `vector`, but you suffer additional indirection and heap memory allocation.

Normally you have objects or complex types and don't have empty elements ready to be changed; rather, an element doesn't exist at all until you add it.  Here you just have `int` values so that is not important.  So, just use a 2D primitive built-in array.

`ability_score_modifier.at(0).at(0) = 1;`
It's strange that you are using `at` rather than the more usual `[]` notation.  Since you are using fixed bounds, even constant subscripts in this example, the difference in error checking is not a reason for it.

---

```
string race;
race = choose_race();
```

You almost had it!  You didn't declare `race` until you were ready to use it, but then you broke it up into two statements.  **initialize** your variables when you declare them.  And, use `const` whenever you can.  Try:

`const string race = choose_race();`

---

`system("cls");`
This is non-portable and slow since it launches another program to clear the screen!  Generally, don't do that as part of a TTY-style program; the user can clear the screen before launching the program if/when he wants.

---

```
    int race_to_integer{};
    if (race == "Human")
    {
        race_to_integer = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (race == "Dwarf")
        {
            race_to_integer = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (race == "Elf")
            {
                race_to_integer = 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

This block should be in its own function at the very least.
It should be part of the get-race stuff, not farther down in the main code.
The races should be an **enumeration type**, not an `int`.

Something like:

```
enum race_type { Human, Dwarf, Elf };
   ⋮
race_type parse_race (string_view in)
{
    if (in=="Human")  return Human;
    if (in=="Dwarf")  return Dwarf;
    if (in=="Elf")  return Elf;
    throw /* something */ ... ;
}
   ⋮
    /* in another function */
    const string race_name= choose_race();
    const auto race = parse_race(race_name);
```

Note that the actual code doesn't have nested nested nested comparisons.  It is flat:  **code to the left**.

Learn to recognise a **cohesive** block of code that should be put into its own function.  You can draw a circle around this and it doesn't interact with anything else.

---

```
case 1:
            check_if_selection_success = false;
            do
            {
                check_if_selection_success = define_strength(strength, unassigned_points);
            } while (check_if_selection_success == false);
            cout << endl;
            break;
```

These cases are almost all the same.  Hoist the looping out to a higher level, and have the menu *only* call one of the functions.

Since the functions, as previously mentioned, should be member functions, you don't need to pass parameters and the menu code becomes simple and compact.

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        if (strength == ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(0))
        {
            strength_mod = ability_score_modifier.at(i).at(1);
        }
    }
```

You have this nearly identical block 6 times in a row!  **Don't Repeat Yourself**.

You are also indexing the same place twice, which is wasteful and hard to read.  In a generic sense, you have:

```
for (const auto& row : ability_score_modifier) {
    if (THING == row[0])  THING_mod= row[1];
}
```

This can be put into a function with the marked placeholders (the only part that changes) becoming parameters.  This is the *real* purpose of parameters in functions:  you have a one-to-one correspondence between the final home of the data and the function parameters, which is not very useful.

But in this case, I think you can just put all 6 THINGs inside the same loop.

I'm really not understanding what your data structure is all about here.  There might be a better way to represent it, based on an understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

### use `else if`

> ```
>           if (i < 13)
>           {
>               required_points++;
>           }
>           else
>           {
>               if (i >= 13 && i < 15)
>               {
>                   required_points += 2;
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                   if (i >= 15 && i < 17)
>                   {
>                       required_points += 3;
>                   }
>                   else
>                   {
>                       required_points += 4;
>                   }
>               }
>           }
> ```

Chains of logic like this can be simplified using `else if`. Each condition is checked in turn, so we can do the following:

```
            if (i < 13)
            {
                required_points++;
            }
            else if (i < 15)
            {
                required_points += 2;
            }
            else if (i < 17)
            {
                required_points += 3;
            }
            else
            {
                required_points += 4;
            }
```

---

### remove duplicate code

There seems to be very little difference between the various `define_[stat]` functions (at a glance, it looks like only the stat name is different?). Consider passing the stat name into the function as a `std::string`. That way we could define a single function, and call it for every stat:

```
bool define_stat(std::string const& name, int& stat, int& unassigned_points);

...

selection_success = define_stat("strength", strength, unsassigned_points);
selection_success = define_stat("wisdom", wisdom, unsassigned_points);
```

It's much easier to maintain 1 function, instead of 6. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is really just too much to go through here. I would suggest you first create classes for the basics. Consider the following code:

```cpp
class Race
{
public:
    Race(std::string name, std::string message)
        : name{ name }, 
          message{ message }
    {
    }

public:
    std::string name;
    std::string message;
};

class Game
{
private:
    std::vector<Race> races;

public:
    Game() {
        races.emplace_back("Human", "In the reckonings of most worlds, humans...");
        races.emplace_back("Dwarf", "Kingdoms rich in ancient grandeur, halls carved...");
        races.emplace_back("Elf", "Elves are a magical people of otherworldly...");
    }

    int chooseRace() {
        std::string errorMessage;
        int raceNumber = -1;
        while (raceNumber == -1)
        {
            if (errorMessage.empty() == false) {
                std::cout << errorMessage << "\n\n";
                errorMessage.clear();
            }

            std::cout << "Select your character race: \n\n";
            int index = 0;
            for (auto race : races)
                std::cout << "[" << ++index << "] " << race.name << "\n";
            std::cout << "\n";

            int number;
            std::cin >> number;
            --number;
            if (number < 0 || number >= races.size())
            {
                errorMessage = "Invalid number";
                continue;
            }
            Race& race = races[number];
            std::cout << race.message << "\n\n";

            std::cout << "Do you confirm your choice? (y/n) --> ";
            char confirm_choice;
            std::cin >> confirm_choice;
            if (confirm_choice == 'y' || confirm_choice == 'Y') {
                raceNumber = number;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return raceNumber;
    }
};

int main() {
    Game game;
    int number = game.chooseRace();
}
```

Adding a new type of 'Race' will be as simple as:

```cpp
    races.emplace_back("Pigmen", "Pigmen belong to Minceraft...");
```

Comment: Good point about making a class, since OP mentioned wanting to learn OOP. However, I would avoid starting member variables with an underscore (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)). I would also write `races.emplace_back(1, "Human, "...")` instead of using `push_back()`, or even better: `static const std::array<Race> races = {{1, "Human", "..."}, {2, "Dwarf", "..."}, ...};` If they are in a vector or array anyway, then `_number` seems a bit superfluous as well.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I have updated my code based on your comments. Do you have any other suggestions, especially about the Race constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Few words from me.

1. I would suggest to extract large texts into separate text files or resources. In you code you just need to load them and simply write on standard output. [Here is an examle (codegrepper.com).](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/cpp/c%2B%2B+load+text+file) I would also suggest to extract smaller text messages into constants.
2. Somebody already mentioned about duplicated code -please do refactor it first. After that, the switch/case conditions could be simplified too. Consider converting a character from user input into lowercase first.
3. main function -please split into smaller subroutines with meaningful names informing what this step really does (their names usually can replace comments in code).